# Laravel - How do I add the System Name to every url without adjusting every routes and ajax urls

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know how can I add the system name to every routes that I have without changing every route on my routes php file, and also without changing every ajax url's that I have.

here is my sample route,

```
/* Maintenance Module */
Route::get('unit_maintenance/','UnitsController@index');

/* Get All */
Route::get('/get_units_all',  'UnitsController@getUnitListAll');

/* Update */
Route::post('/unit/update/{id}','UnitsController@setUnitList');

/* Save New */
Route::post('save_unit/','UnitsController@store');
```

and also I have lot's of ajax urls,

is there anyway I can make it like this,

http://ipaddress/systemName/route/

without changing everything one by one, including my ajax urls,

Thank You!

Comment: - you should use named routes and then can easily possible to make changes on one place like in routes.php file and prefix the routes accordingly,

Comment: the moment I had to add a system name on every route  I realized it's main purpose. but can I use the named routes on ajax url?

Comment: Yes, you have to use named routes in all views. it's best approach to use named routes, as if you want to make changes in the routes then you will only have to make changes in the routes.php file, not views.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Route Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-groups).

For Laravel <= 5.3

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'systemName'], function () {

    /* Maintenance Module */
    Route::get('unit_maintenance/','UnitsController@index');

    /* Get All */
    Route::get('/get_units_all',  'UnitsController@getUnitListAll');

    /* Update */
    Route::post('/unit/update/{id}','UnitsController@setUnitList');

    /* Save New */
    Route::post('save_unit/','UnitsController@store');

});
```

For Laravel > 5.3

```
Route::prefix('systemName')->group(function () {

    /* Maintenance Module */
    Route::get('unit_maintenance/','UnitsController@index');

    /* Get All */
    Route::get('/get_units_all',  'UnitsController@getUnitListAll');

    /* Update */
    Route::post('/unit/update/{id}','UnitsController@setUnitList');

    /* Save New */
    Route::post('save_unit/','UnitsController@store');

});
```

Comment: if i do that, would I have to change all my redirects and ajax urls? 
like, from ajax url: '/get_units_all' to '/systemName/get_units_all' ?

Comment: you will need to change too, all urls are changed and have a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to tho this is put everithing inside a Route prefix!

Something like that:

```
Route::prefix('systemName')->group(function () {

     //All your rotes inside 

});
```

Im afraid you will need to change your ajax or just redirect the old routes like this:

```
Route::redirect('/here', '/there', 301);
```